# Can we stop termination of app in between XCUITests cases?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

Can we stop termination of app in between XCUITests cases?

I am running 30  UI test cases in which I wanted to run continuously without termination of app using XCUITests.

Comment: I'm doing the stackoverflow cliche, but you really shouldn't have to be doing this. The idea behind killing between is to prevent previous failures from cascading and ruining a whole batch. Maybe give your tests more asserts so that it's longer and covers more?

Comment: I agree with Sirens; the framework prevents you from being able to run the app continuously throughout multiple tests to encourage best practice for tests being independent from one another.

Comment: The KIF framework allows the app to not quit between tests. It is based on XCTest though.

Answer (score 1):

In such case, you should launch your application once in your first test method, not in the `setUp` method.

But bare in mind that the execution order of the test methods is not specified. Methods can run in different order using `Product -> Test` and different when you run from "Test Navigator"